# Configuring libjpeg in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, libjpeg

I want to congfigure libjpeg in VS10. I found this guide  http://www.leptonica.org/vs2008doc/building-image-libraries.html and downloaded the archive of the library from the same site.The problem is that in the guide is mentioned some file jpeg.sln, but this file is not present in the downloaded archive. I would be happy if someone can help me.

Comment: Run `nmake -f makefile.vc setup-v10` to create the jpeg.sln file.

Comment: Sorry,  Can you write again the command for generating the jpeg.sln file.It seems that now the error with the location is fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a jpeg.prj in the package?

Normally, opening (double-clicking) the .prj file automatically creates a .sln file if one with the same base name isn't already present in that folder.

If there isn't, then do what @HansPassant suggested: Run `nmake -f makefile.vc setup-v10` to create the jpeg.sln file.

**Note:** NMAKE must be in your exec path. If it isn't, go to **Start Button** > `All Programs` > `Microsoft Visual Studio 10` > `Visual Studio Tools` > `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)` and then run the above command.

I just tried it. It generates the `jpeg.sln` file like a charm (along with other necessary files like `jpeg.vcxproj` etc.)

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual C++ Express 2010
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "jpeg", "jpeg.vcxproj", "{019DBD2A-273D-4BA4-BF86-B5EFE2ED76B1}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {019DBD2A-273D-4BA4-BF86-B5EFE2ED76B1}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {019DBD2A-273D-4BA4-BF86-B5EFE2ED76B1}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: @thecoder Did you try what Hans Passant suggested? It seems to make sense, although I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I tried and I think that what he said is completely correct, but it seems that my system has some problem.

Comment: It's possible that your NMAKE isn't in the PATH. I just downloaded the package and discovered a file named `makeasln.v10`. Try that.

Comment: Yes I did like that, but when I open the VS cmd it appears some error that the location of the folder VS Common Tools can't be determined.

Comment: Ah, that's a fundamental problem in the installation of your VS. I am posting the content of jpeg.sln, but I don't think it would be of much help if your dev env isn't installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no luck, how about using BMP image file? I think you could read the BMP file without Independent JPEG Group library (details at http://dlib.net/image_ex.cpp.html.)

If you still want to use JPEG file, you may consider using OpenCV in your code. First open JPG in OpenCV function and convert it to Dlib format using

cv_image img(your_opencv_image);

(details at http://sourceforge.net/p/dclib/discussion/442518/thread/6ef452cc/)